# CI cache unable to pass provider configurations through stages

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have usual stages in a terraform CI i.e. `init` > `validate` > `plan` etc. The first step i.e. `init` works fine always.
But when we reach the next stage for e.g. `validate` I get following error:

```
$ terraform validate
103╷
104│ Error: Missing required provider
105│ 
106│ This configuration requires provider registry.terraform.io/datadog/datadog,
107│ but that provider isn't available. You may be able to install it
108│ automatically by running:
109│ terraform init
110╵
```

1. Now if a run `init` in the same stage as `validate` it works fine. So basically, a workaround is to either have all commands in one stage or have `init` at every stage, neither of which is ideal of course.
2. If I login to runner server and manually browse the `.terraform` directory the provider `executable` is there. But if I run `terraform validate` from shell it will again fail with the same error, however if I run `init` and then `validate` now it works.
3. No changes in `.terraform` directory and its contents before and after `init`. Same files, just updated creation datetimes.
4. If I go back to gitlab and re-run the `validate` stage which will fail but then I came back to server shell and do `terraform validate` again it will again fail, again no obvious changes in directory contents or permissions. Do `init` again and it will start working again.

As per my understanding the only difference between these stages is cache zip/unzip since `.terraform` folder is passed on as a cache.

In job console I can see following message:

```
Checking cache for terraform...
Runtime platform arch=amd64 os=linux pid=3798191 revision=90daeee0 version=14.7.0
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
```

Another thing to notice is though downloaded modules are also present in `.terraform` it never throws an error regarding module but only about providers. I guess its something to do with `.exe` files?

`config.toml`:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "cicd_terraform"
  url = "***"
  token = "****"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
```

Earlier, an empty `runners.cache` section was there but situation was same so i removed it. I want it to use local directory as cache.

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
cache:
  key: terraform
  paths:
    - .terraform


before_script:
  - echo -e "credentials \"$CI_SERVER_HOST\" {\n  token = \"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"\n}" > $TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE
  - cd ${TF_ROOT}
  - export TF_LOG_CORE=TRACE
  - export TF_LOG_PATH=${TF_ROOT}/terraform_logs.txt
  - ls -al
  - ls -al ${TF_ROOT}
  - echo "$TF_ROOT"


stages:
  - initialize
  - validate

init:
  stage: initialize
  script:
    - terraform -v
    - terraform init -backend-config="*****" -backend-config="*****.tfstate" -backend-config="*****-1" -backend-config="access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" -backend-config="secret_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" -input=false -no-color

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
```

`ls -al ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/datadog/datadog/2.24.0/linux_amd64`

```
total 29256
drwxr-xr-x 2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Feb 19 01:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Feb 19 01:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    48216 Feb 19 01:36 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    16725 Feb 19 01:36 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    12450 Feb 19 01:36 LICENSE-3rdparty.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     1524 Feb 19 01:36 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 29859840 Feb 19 01:36 terraform-provider-datadog_v2.24.0
```

Any idea, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wait, do you have maybe a `.terraform.lock.hcl` file which references binary for Windows and you are trying to use it on a Linux build system? Because you mentioned `.exe` file.

Comment: @MarkoE No, my bad i just meant the `executable`, i also update the questions with `ls` output of directory

Comment: Ah, I think you are missing `${TF_ROOT}` in front of the `.terraform`, i.e. `paths` should be `${TF_ROOT}/.terraform`.

Comment: tried it doesn't work, that was actually the original configuration removed it to see if it will change something, but no.

Comment: And did you add `cd ${TF_ROOT}` in both `init` and `validate` stages prior to running the `terraform init` and `terraform validate`?

Comment: its part of the `before_script:` so I believe it runs before every stage?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is true. And can you set the cache key to be `${TF_ROOT}` and paths to be `${TF_ROOT}/.terraform` and try that?

Comment: `cache:
  key: ${TF_ROOT}
  paths:
    - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform
` 
same results :( .

Comment: I forgot quotation marks in the key name, sorry, it should be `key: "${TF_ROOT}"`. Btw, have you defined the value for `TF_ROOT` in the `variables` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things must be true in order for Terraform to be able to find a particular provider:

1. [The `.terraform.lock.hcl` file](https://www.terraform.io/language/files/dependency-lock) must specify a selected version for that provider, and the allowed plugin checksums for that version.
2. There must be a package for that selected version in `.terraform/providers` -- the local plugin cache directory -- which matches one of the checksums.

From what you shared it seems like the second of these is being handled by you passing the cache between steps using features of your CI system.

In order for the first to be true though, you'll need to run `terraform init` on your development machine in order to generate the `.terraform.lock.hcl` file and then check that file into version control as part of your configuration, which will hopefully then make your CI system place it in the right place as a normal part of checking out the source code.

When running `terraform init` in a non-interactive environment like this I would suggest adding the `-lockfile=readonly` option, which will cause Terraform to fail with an error if the lock file has become inconsistent with the rest of the configuration. That'll then allow your CI system to catch this problem early in the first step and return an explicit error about it, whereas in your current workflow `terraform init` can update the lock file itself but that then doesn't carry forward to the other steps, causing strange downstream errors.

Comment: ah, thankyou so much it worked, i had to check in the `.terraform.lock.hcl` which was missing and all moved into right direction.

Comment: For nay future viewers, since my local environment is on windows and CI on linux so i did faced `provider checksum mismatch` error, which got resolved with this `terraform providers lock -platform=windows_amd64 -platform=darwin_amd64 -platform=linux_amd64`

Comment: Indeed that can happen if you've configured your local system to install providers from anywhere other than their origin registries, because in that case Terraform can't rely on the full set of signed checksums from that registry when populating the lock file. `terraform providers lock` allows forcing the inclusion of particular checksums by calculating the checksums locally, but you can avoid the need to do that by removing any unusual provider installation configuration and thus allowing `terraform init` to access `registry.terraform.io` directly and get the full set of checksums from there.

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't really matter which way you do it as long as you get checksums for every OS you need in there, but the default `terraform init` behavior has the advantage that you don't need to actually download any package other than the one for your current platform, because it can find all of the checksums in the remote registry, signed by the provider developer.